# std::bind c++ in if statement

Tags: c++, std

I am working with some legacy code for a school project and am trying to capture if std::bind fails.  This is the code currently in the project (not written by me) that is producing "C++ no operator matches these operands" error in VS 2019.  I've tried comparing against a bool which is what it says std::bind returns to no avail.

```
if ( bind( socket, (const sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "failed to bind socket\n" );
    Close();
    return false;
}
```

How else can I properly capture if std::bind fails within an if statement?

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace std;` before this code?  It's likely trying to call `std::bind` which is for binding arguments to a function, version the socket.h `bind` which is what you want.  Try changing `bind(...` to `::bind(`

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong function.  standard C++ introduced `std::bind` but it isn't for sockets.

Comment: std::bind (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is not bind (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)

Comment: Are you perhaps writing `using namespace std`? That is considered bad practice. I guess the bind isn't under a specific namespace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code, so if you are assuming namespace std, then the bind is automatically assumed to be std::bind rather than bind.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function does not return a value on failure, it throws an exception instead.

But the code you have shown is NOT trying to use `std::bind()` at all, it is actually trying to use the WinSock [`bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind) function instead, but it can't because `std::bind()` is in scope due to a previous `using namespace std;` or `using std::bind;` statement (most likely the former), and so the compiler is trying to call `std::bind()` instead.

You need to either [get rid of the `using` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/), or else prefix the `bind()` call with the `::` global [scope resolution operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers):

```cpp
if ( ::bind( socket, (const sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) ) < 0 )
```